# Duplicate question advice

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, moderation

I'm a pretty active user in [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery). I have been an active user for about 8 months now and I'm having a problem with a particular type of duplicate question.

The question has to do with why event handlers don't fire, or why widgets invoked on selected elements don't work on content loaded via AJAX or appended dynamically in some other fashion. **There are so many duplicates of this *exact* problem:**

- [jQuery not working in AJAX Loaded page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1419433/497356)
- [Making Jquery work within a page that was received via ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6714734/497356)
- [Jquery not working in Ajax calls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1092450/497356)
- [Jquery not working on html called in from Ajax scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5652231/497356)

**The list goes on and on and on**. It's even hard to search for questions like these because the problems sometimes involve particular events, functions being called, etc., etc.

**I would love to start closing these as duplicates.**

However, I can't find a solid, well worded question and answer that I can link to when I would like to close it as a duplicate (please let me know if you find one that does).

At first as a new user I welcomed these problems ("OH I know that! Easy rep!"), but now I believe that posts like these are just cluttering the tag up.

I thought of two options:

1. Write a question and answer it myself (or let the community answer it) just for the purposes of getting a decent question that encompasses issues of this type so that we can redirect people to it and start closing these types of questions.
2. Add an entry in the tag wiki. This is probably a good idea, but how many casual/new users are actually perusing the tag wiki?

I'm sure this isn't the only situation in which a question manifests itself in different ways. What's the best way to deal with duplicates of this nature?

Comment: Improve an existing question, post a canonical answer, and close all others as duplicates of that one. Same deal as I suggested [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98410/how-best-to-deal-with-a-faq-thats-not-recognized-as-such/98414#98414). Hard to see what the problem is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#1 is the best solution. However, make sure that even the initial answer is fairly comprehensive, and aim for a broad and comprehensive but *detailed* answer.

Comment: Thanks. I figured this was the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend #1, that you create a question and answer it yourself. But I would make it community wiki so users don't eye your reputation and assume you're trying to cash in on the easy reputation and badges made by basic questions. And, of course, it would be more honest given your intention.

Comment: I disagree with this. If you spend time composing a question or answer that others in the community find helpful and choose to upvote, then you deserve all the reputation you get from those upvotes.